# Setting click priority on google maps polygon array

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am coding in JavaScript using the Google Maps API, and I was curious if there was a way to set the priority of what polygon array info window is shown when I click on an area. I have two polygons that are overlapping, and I need to control which info bubble appears when you click on the overlapped area. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The click will be triggered on the most top Polygon.

The order of the polygons usually depends on the order in which they have been added to the map(when the `map`-property has been set) or by setting a custom `zIndex`-property.

So when you want  to define a priority you must define the `zIndex` for the Polygons.

When you want to be able to click on each polygon(and each part of each polygon) there is a simple approach:

Observe the mouseover of the polygons and set the `zIndex` of the hovered polygon to a value higher than the zIndex of the other polygons. This will bring the polygon into front and you now may also click on the previously covered area.

You may implement this by extending the polygon-prototype:

```
(function(){
  var a=z=0;
  google.maps.Polygon_=function(opts){


     this.setValues(opts)
     google.maps.event.addListener(this,'mouseover',function(){
        this.set('zIndex',++z);
     });    
     google.maps.event.addListener(this,'rightclick',function(){
        this.set('zIndex',--a);
     });

  };
  google.maps.Polygon_.prototype = google.maps.Polygon.prototype;
  google.maps.Polygon = google.maps.Polygon_;}
)();
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/wznd5nsy/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/wznd5nsy/)

(Use rightclick to send a polygon to back, e.g. when it completely covers another polygon).